# Using Friends' Data for Generating Recommendations

Tags: facebook, policy

I have a question about II(4): "A user's friends' data can only be used in the context of the user's experience on your application."

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

We're building an application that uses Facebook user (and a user's friends' data) to generate intelligent recommendations. Are we allowed to use data gathered from friends' for those recommendations? In a small way, everybody's (whether or not they are a friend) recommendations will be affected by the new friend data.

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be an issue. See some of the social readers out there like Yahoo! News, WSJ, Washington Post, etc... they all show a listing of articles that your friends have read, along with your friends names and photos.

Using this data to give strangers recommendations is a little more grey though...

But how the policy you are referring to is worded, using the user's friends' data will enhance the user's experience..

Of the policy questions I have seen, this one is pretty clear cut (meaning black and white, and not grey) in my opinion. Enjoy!

Chris

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm not sure that I completely follow. To be more clear, here is how the application could be impacted by the policy referenced above. There are users A and B. User A has a bunch of friends who are not users, but who through the FB API we are able to gather information about. The information about the friends of user A then influence the recommendations of user B, even though user A's friends are not user B's friends. Does that violate the policy above where it says that "A user's friends' data can ONLY be used in the context of the user's experience on your application" ?

Comment: I don't totally follow either.  In the case of this application, using friends' data will enhance both the user's experience AND the experience of other users (who may not be acquainted with the friends in question). Do the Facebook terms prohibit using the friends' data for this purpose (since using the friends' data enhances the experience of users who may not be acquainted with those friends)?